# StyleCop SA1649 rule not being honored

Tags: .net, stylecop, editorconfig

The rule SA1649 is under Documentation category but is not being honored when I add "`dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-Documentation.severity = error`" in .editorconfig file.
It's also not followed when I explicitly add it as "`dotnet_diagnostic.SA1649.severity = error`". I'm using VisualStudio 2022.
Does anyone have a workaround for this?